# How to use third party components on Razor class library?

Tags: razor, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor solution I created some shared components using the net core and SyncFusion components. It works perfectly, but now I'm trying to move these components to a Razor Class Library (named "AppComponentsShared")

These are the steps I've done so far in the Razor Class Library project:

1. Installed the SyncFunction package.It is visible in Dependencies->Packages->SyncFusion.Blazor
2. Added "@using Syncfusion.Blazor" in the _Imports.razor 
   At this point the Syncfusion becomes red and on mouse over it pops the following:
   "The type or namespace 'SyncFusion' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or    an assembly reference?"

Comment: You need to provide more information especially code. We are writing our wrapper components for the Telerik Blazor components in an Razor class library and it works.

Comment: @boindiil  Please, see the updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the target framework from 2.0 to 2.1 (in your csproj file):

```
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Syncfusion changed to netstandard2.1: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/release-notes/17.4.39/